# Как реализовать метод определения точки многоугольнику. Метод учёт числа оборотов

Tags: c++, графика, вычислительная-геометрия

мне необходимо реализовать метод **учет числа оборотов**, подскажите пожалуйста алгоритм моих действий. На данный момент у меня сформирован следующий список действий, одна в некоторых моментах я запутался:

1. Ставим точку, выпускаем луч в произвольном направлении.
2. Рассматриваем рёбра которые он пересекает
3. Если луч пересекает ребро сверху вниз то +1 если снизу вверх то -1
4. Суммируем то что получили в 3 п.
5. Если сумма 0 то точка вне многоугольника иначе в многоугольнике.

**Собственно запутался я в том, что говорится о параметрическом виде**, написано - прямые в параметрическом виде. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно реализовать данный метод.
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: А где именно написано что в параметрическом? Я когда делал этот алгоритм там по координатам точек спокойно можно сделать

Comment: @trollingchar преподаватель говорил про прямые в параметрическом виде

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку луч можно выпускать в любом направлении, разумно выбрать то, что даст решение попроще - например, горизонтальное направление. При этом для определения пересечения с ребром достаточно того, что начальная и конечная точки имеют Y-координаты больше (или равно) и меньше (или равно), чем точка. Надо только аккуратно обрабатывать ребра с одним концом, лежащим на луче, или с обоими (т.е. всё ребро лежит на прямой, содержащей луч).

[Известный чудесный код](https://wrf.ecse.rpi.edu//Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html) эти тонкости учитывает

```
int pnpoly(int nvert, float *vertx, float *verty, float testx, float testy)
{
  int i, j, c = 0;
  for (i = 0, j = nvert-1; i < nvert; j = i++) {
    if ( ((verty[i]>testy) != (verty[j]>testy)) &&
     (testx < (vertx[j]-vertx[i]) * (testy-verty[i]) / 
                         (verty[j]-verty[i]) + vertx[i]) )
       c = !c;
  }
  return c;
}
```